# Providing external functionality to existing ReactJS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I have a simple ReactJS 3-step form which consumers use to request tech support from our partners.

Until now, the support request form was universal for all of our partners (name, email, problem)

Now, I'd like to for a specific partner, add additional form elements. Ideally this should be customizable on a per-partner basis. Example, Partner A, would like to also capture the serial number of the device. Partner B would like to have the customer agree to a terms of service.

To solve this, I am passing along an optional component to my form. If there, it is rendered. I have not figured out how to access the optional components data, and pass it along as an opaque data field as part of the request submission.

**Question**

In the code below, in `Form` how can I access the state of `FormOverride`?

Or, is there a more idomatic way to achieve what I am looking for?

Unlike a parent / child hierarchy where a parent can access the child state in a number of ways, the `FormOverride` component is instantiated outside of the `Form` hierarchy, and passed as a property.

```
import React from "react";

const Form = ({ override }) => {
  
  //universal form state
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (override) {
      //get the state value from override component
    }

    alert("Clicked");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Contact Info</h3>
      {override}
      <h3>Support Details</h3>
      <h3>Case Summary</h3>

      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
};

const FormOverride = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {

  const someValue = "composed";

  let toRender = null;

  if (someValue === "default") {
    toRender = <Form/>;
  }

  if (someValue === "composed") {
    toRender = <Form override=<FormOverride /> />;
  }

  return <div className="App">{toRender}</div>;
}
```

[I also have a sandbox of the above.](https://codesandbox.io/s/composed-react-vxoeu?file=/src/App.js:23-986)

Comment: Basically, you need to use inversion of control. If you change your component to optionally take children then it can be customized by anyone

Comment: This may help: https://dev.to/loweisz/use-the-inversion-of-control-pattern-with-react-4k72

Comment: Maybe you can export a function in your component through a context provider that a child component can use in its own changeEvents. You don't access the data directly. They give it to you.

Comment: You would have to keep all of the form state in the parent for submission.

Comment: @DovRine The parent has the form general form state, but I'm hoping to have the state that is unique to the additional component wholly housed in that component. Or if not, allow having opaque state at the parent level, and allow that override to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, a global state manager like **Redux** is helpful but you can implement it without a global state manager with the `state lift up` technique (as you mentioned in the comments) but in a tricky way:

Let's implement a state in the `App` component and pass it to the related components:

```
export default function App() {
  const [textOverride, setTextOverride] = React.useState("");

  const someValue = "composed";

  let toRender = null;

  if (someValue === "default") {
    toRender = <SomeComponent />;
  }

  if (someValue === "composed") {
    toRender = (
      <SomeComponent
        override={<ComposedValue getOverrideText={setTextOverride} />}
        textOverride={textOverride}
      />
    );
  }

  return <div className="App">{toRender}</div>;
}
```

As you see, `getOvverideText` props were passed to the `ComposedValue`, so we need to call it when the input changes.

```
const ComposedValue = ({ getOverrideText }) => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    setText(value);
    getOverrideText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, the `textOvveride` value (which we defined in the `App`) is up to date with text input changes. so we can easily use the `textOverride` value in the `SomeComponent` as below:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ override, textOverride }) => {

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (override) {
      //get the state value from override component
    }

    alert(textOverride);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Contact Info</h3>
      {override}
      <h3>Support Details</h3>
      <h3>Case Summary</h3>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Note:** I prefer using a `Global State Manager` like Redux to do such things within as the above implementation is hard to debug and change.
The bad side of this implementation is `SomeComponent` will re-render with every single change in the `input` element.

**Note:** there is no way to get the `overrideText` as you call the `handleSubmit` function because there aren't child-parent components. But, with using such tools as Redux, you can ignore the extra re-render and get the `overrideText` at same the time as calling the `handleSubmit` function.

**Note:** I guess you simplified the components to demonstrate your purpose, otherwise using an independent `input` element inside of the `SomeComponent` will reduce the codes and the procedure to get the changes from another component.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I simplified the example. Since Redux is a viable option to solve this problem would that also mean using the Context API also be a solution? Create a provide that creates override state, and allow any "extension" components to write directly to that state object?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can also use the ContextApi solution as you mentioned it in the correct way @Alan . best regards.

Comment: hope the answer was helpful Sir @Alan . please accept the answer if it really solved the issue. best regards.

Comment: thanks I will once I have a chance to implement it. Best.